# Disable line wrapping and horizontal scrolling for output in iTerm

Tags: terminal, command-line

I want to disable the interactive line wrapping that iterm does in my terminal application.

I can run

```
$ python -c 'print "\x1b[?7l"'
```

to disable line wrapping *on output*, so long lines like

```
$ python -c 'print "asdf"*100'
```

don't immediately get line wrapped and instead are cut off, but once I interactively change the window width to be smaller that line still wraps. I'd like behavior like vim has when in `set nowrap` mode - not even a flicker of a wrap.

This question is similar to [Disable line wrapping for output in the Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/disable-line-wrapping-for-output-in-the-terminal), but that's asking about scrolling.

Comment: Ah, I now believe this is only possible by using the terminal fullscreen mode, something like python -c 'print "\x1b[?1049h"'

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not possible without using fullscreen mode - vim is using fullscreen mode (`python -c 'print "\x1b[?1049h"'`) which disables vertical scrolling as well, which isn't what I want (though this wasn't clear in the question).

Also, it turns out this behavior isn't specific to terminal.app - it's how all the terminals I've tried work.